# Matching with Ltac on a call containing local variable

Tags: coq, ltac

I have a goal that contains a call to some lemma `foo` within branch of a match. That call uses as one of its arguments a variable `R` local to the branch:

```
| SomeConstr => fun R => .... (foo a b c R) ....
```

I would like to perform beta expansion on `foo` so that the call becomes:

```
| SomeConstr => fun R => .... ((fun d => foo a b c d) R) ....
```

This will allow me to further generalize `(fun d => foo a b c d)`, which will no loner rely on variables local to a branch. Since I am dealing with very large proofs I would like to write this using Ltac. Here's an attempt:

```
match goal with
| [ |- context[(foo ?A ?B ?C ?R)] ] =>
  let d := fresh "d" in
  replace (foo A B C R) with ((fun d => foo A B C d) R)
end.
```

That however fails with "No matching clause for match". If I replace body of the `match` branch with `idtac` it still fails, so the problem is clearly cause by failing to match a given expression. However, if I match one argument less then the match succeeds. For example:

```
match goal with
| [ |- context[(foo ?A ?B ?C)] ] =>
  idtac A; idtac B; idtac C
end.
```

prints "a", "b" and "c" in consequtive lines. I can also say:

```
match goal with
| [ |- context[(foo ?A ?B ?C)] ] =>
  let d := fresh "d" in
  replace (foo A B C) with (fun d => foo A B C d) by auto
end.
```

and this succeeds, but interestingly the goal remains unchaged, ie. the call is still in the form `(foo a b c R)` and not `((fun d => foo a b c d) R)`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `replace` tactic performs β reduction.  You can see this by writing

```
Goal True.
  replace True with ((fun x => x) True) by auto.
```

If you instead use the `change` tactic (which only works when side-condition of `replace` could be solved by `reflexivity`), then it should work.  For example,

```
Goal True.
  change True with ((fun x => x) True).
```

changes the goal to `(fun x : Prop => x) True`.

This is undocumented, and I have reported it as [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/6684).